# java basic code challenge

Tags: java

What is wrong with this code? It compiles and runs fine but codewars says "The code does not work as expected"

Challenge: Correct this code, so that the greet function returns the expected value.

```
public class Person {
  String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
            this.name = personName;  // all I had to do was add 'this'
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
            return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

> The code does not work as expected

Comment: Just a guess, but they might be expecting "this.name" in the greet function as well.

Comment: Adding `this` to use `this.name` won't change anything in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be strange, but probably the answer is to swap the `name` and `yourName`?

```
return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
```

This way the message looks more logical.

Comment: thanks Tagir for your answer! (covers face in shame)